# WIF: Possible to use without active directotry?

Tags: wif

Is it possible to use Windows Identity Foundation without Active directory?

I thought i could, but the vast majority of what i am finding uses it at some point.
Am i just using crappy search terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. In fact WIF is never used against AD directly, but through ADFS (another component in Windows).

You can use WIF with any identity provider that implements the WS-Federation protocol and issues SAML tokens.

Look here for examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx or the Identity Training Kit (or event the WIF SDK samples)

Answer (score 1):

I use thinktecture as my STS and use WIF as the framework to talk to the STS.

WIF is just a framework which provides support for claims authentication and has nothing to do with ADFS.  ADFS is just an STS wrapper over Active Directory which provides MMC configuration for setting up relying parties and providing claims transforms.  In my experience it is lacking some of the requirements for modern cloud type applications and often requires additional services (ACS) to provide modern token formats.

ADFS only supports SAML.

More information on how this works can be found on my blog here:

http://garymcallisteronline.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-4-adfs-20-and-3rd-party-sts.html